# get data from javascript array using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

After several frustrating hours, I turn to the stackoverflow group for some help.  While I know that regex can solve my problem, I do not know enough (and am on a deadline, so can't learn what I need before the deadline) to do what I need to do.

My issue is that I have the following array:

```
(['ad53930','160x600','&PG=SPTRF3','&AP=1090','regular'],
['ad55852','728x90','&PG=SPTRF1','&AP=1390','regular'],
['ad52971','300x250_pginterstitial','&PG=SPTRF4','&AP=1089','pgInterstitial'],
['ad52969','300x250','&PG=SPTHP4','&AP=1089','regular'])
```

and need to extract the 6 digit code after the &PG=.  I was able to hobble together some regex to pull the entire `&PG=XXXXXX` string, but built it in Chrome's console, and after the browser crashed, lost the regex.  What I am trying to accomplish is to get a finished product of 'SPTRF3,SPTRF1,SPTRF4,SPTHP4' from the array above, either in another array or string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your variable an actual array, or a string representation of an array?

Comment: It's an actual array...the entire array code is: var ads = new Array(['ad53930','160x600','&PG=SPTRF3','&AP=1090','regular'],['ad55852','728x90','&PG=SPTRF1','&AP=1390','regular'],['ad52971','300x250_pginterstitial','&PG=SPTRF4','&AP=1089','pgInterstitial'],['ad52969','300x250','&PG=SPTHP4','&AP=1089','regular']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need regular expressions? You can just use a substring on that string in the array: `.substr(3)`.

If the "&PG=" string is always in the array at index `2`, then you can iterate through the array of arrays like this:

```
for (idx in myArray)
   console.log(myArray[idx][2].substr(4), ",");
```

Comment: The client said that it is currently in the 3rd position, but this may change depending on if another string is added to the beginning of the array...

Comment: Ideally, you'd represent this data as an object instead. I realize you may have no control over that. So if you can't rely on it being in position `2`, then you'll have to iterate each sub-array and see if `.substr(0, 3)` is equal to `&PG` first (or something like that).

Comment: .indexOf would help with that https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: True. indexOf would probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex capture groups, pass this regex to every item with a `for` loop and push results to another array `products`

```
var products = []
for (var i=0, l=arr.length, p; i<l; i++){
  p = /&PG\=(.+)/.exec(arr[i])[1]
  if (p) products.push(p)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
/&PG=[A-Z]{5}\d/g
```

Comment: This returns the entire string including the "$PG=".  What I am trying to do is to only get the 6 digits after the $PG=.

Comment: Oh Yes sorry try this: /(?!&PG=)[A-Z]{5}\d/g although if you're using javascript this won't because it doesn't support negative lookahead.

Comment: You can try var letters = /&PG=([A-Z]{5}\d)/g; var matchs = []; for i in yourArray() {matchs += i.match(letters)[2];} I don't use regex in js much so I'm not sure how that'll do but it should work.

Comment: Sorry I posted that comment before it was done. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

it may work for you.

```
var arr = ['ad53930','160x600','&PG=SPTRF3','&AP=1090','regular']
var num = arr[2].substr(4); // it will give SPTRF3
```